# Split day agenda in full calendar into 15-minute slots

Tags: javascript, php, split, fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
      },
      buttonText: {
        today: 'today',
        month: 'month',
        week: 'week',
        day: 'day'
      },
      //Random default events
      events : <?php echo json_encode($events1);?>,

      editable: true,
      droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
      drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
```

i need to split into 15 minutes interval.the default is 30 minutes slots.how can i achieve it  thank u in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `slotDuration`: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/

Comment: ty u for ur reply im new to calendar and that seems to be the solution but i have no idea in which part to put the line any ideas ?

Comment: @HenriSula Just add a property `slotDuration: '00:15:00'`.